# C++ #define macro for functions

Tags: c++, macros

I have a header file for definitions . I want to have a max and min function for each built-in type .

I use the following macro :

```
#define DEFINE__MIN_MAX(type) \
   inline type max(type x, type y) { return (x>y) ?  x : y ; } \
   inline type min(type x, type y) { return (x<y) ?  x : y ; }
```

Now I call the macro to specialize short data-type

```
DEFINE_MIN_MAX(short)  // Error: type 'short' unexpected .
```

I am trying this in Windows using QtCreator 3.0.1 . I am not sure how to deal with this error.

Any inputs are welcome .

Comment: You're using a [reserved identifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). These already exist in `<algorithm>` as templates.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't toss the macros and just use a (pair of) template function(s)?

Comment: You effectively accomplished a function template with extra work. mah is right, you should just write a function template.

Comment: @chris : I have not included <algorithm> . It should not recognize max and min as already defined , ins't it ?

Comment: @user3389943, Some other header could still include it. Anyway, my point was to use the ones in there instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Also `windows.h` has these identifiers defined, albeit in a very foolish way

Answer (score 1):

Trivial error: you have a double underscore in the definition, but use only one underscore in the call. Change the line

```
#define DEFINE__MIN_MAX(type) \
```

to

```
#define DEFINE_MIN_MAX(type) \
```

and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Stay away from macros. C++ provides type-safe replacements for almost all standard usages of macros. For your case, where you want a min and max function for every type T, express this as a template:

```
template<typename T> T const& min(T const& x, T const& y) {
    return (x < y) ? (x) : (y);
}

template<typename T> T const& max(T const& x, T const& y) {
    return (x > y) ? (x) : (y);
}
```

Or use `std::min` and `std::max` from the standard library.

Comment: Nice. This enables moving in cases like `Int useMoveContructor(min(Int(1), Int(2)));` if Int has a move constructor, right? I wonder why even in C++14 std::min and std::max are still defined as in my answer. Backwards compatibility?

Comment: wait, I just realized my code was wrong, and wouldn't compile since it could not determine the return type at compile time >.<

Comment: Still I think it would make sense to define the functions like `template<typename T> T&& min(T&& x, T&& y) {return (x < y) ? (std::forward<T>(x)) : (std::forward<T>(y));}` on C++11. Any idea why std::min is not defined that way?

Comment: backwards compatibility I'd assume, though I'm not sure anyone can say for certain